# Why am I losing number at risk when I convert the ggsurvplot to plotly?

Tags: plotly

In my code, gr produces the basic survival plot with the number at risk at the bottom.  But when I convert it to plotly, plotlygr produces the interactive but no longer includes the number at risk.  Is there any way to keep the interactive plot in plotly without losing the number at risk at the bottom?

```
# Fit survival curves
require("survival")
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

# Basic survival curves
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = TRUE)

# Customized survival curves
gr <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung,
           surv.median.line = "hv", # Add medians survival
           
           # Change legends: title & labels
           legend.title = "Sex",
           legend.labs = c("Male", "Female"),
           # Add p-value and tervals
           pval = TRUE,
           
           # Add risk table
           risk.table = TRUE,
           tables.height = 0.2,
           tables.theme = theme_cleantable(),
           
           # Color palettes. Use custom color: c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF"),
           # or brewer color (e.g.: "Dark2"), or ggsci color (e.g.: "jco")
           palette = c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF"),
           ggtheme = theme_bw() # Change ggplot2 theme
)


gr

plotlygr <- plotly::ggplotly(gr$plot)
plotlygr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list indexing to get survival plot and risk table differently and then combine them using subplots:

```
survival_obj <- plotly::ggplotly(gr[[1]])
risk_obj <- plotly::ggplotly(gr[[2]])

final_plotly_obj <- plotly::subplot(survival_obj, risk_obj , nrows = 2, heights=c(0.8, 0.2)
```